# How to toggle a boolean field in one document with atomic operation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there any way to toggle the boolean field of ONE document in MongoDB with atomic operation? Say, (In python)

```
cl.update({"_id": ...}, {"$toggle": {"field": 1}})
```

Comment: Operations on seperate document are atomic, but operations on set of documents are not atomic. Do you mean you need to change flag for all documents of collection?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make this clear. I would like operations on seperate document.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right now, I don't think it's possible to do this with one operation. The bitwise operators (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24bit) don't have a '$xor' yet although I've a patch for it.

Right now the workaround I think think of is by always using '$inc':

```
cl.update( { "_id": ...}, { '$inc' : { 'field' : 1 } } );
```

Then instead of checking for true or false, you can do check whether an item is "true":

```
cl.find( { "_id": ..., 'field' : { '$mod' : [ 2, 1 ] } );
```

IE, you using the modulo operator to see whether it's even or uneven with even being "unset", and uneven being "set". If you want to have the oppposite behaviour (ie, find all items that don't have the flag set), then use

```
[ 2, 0 ];
```

Comment: Nice solution, proposed similar in #mongodb ;) Ticket as a result of that conversation here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4362

Comment: This will not scale very well, as you'll do a collection scan every time you do a query.

Answer (score 9):

The [SERVER-4362](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4362) issue is actually resolved now and you have the [`$bit`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/) update operator available. So along with it's [`xor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/#bitwise-xor) argument you can now do this in an atomic action:

```js
cl.findOneAndUpdate( 
  { "_id": ...}, 
  { 
     "$bit": { 
         "field": { "xor": NumberInt(1) } 
     } 
  },
  { "returnNewDocument": true, "upsert": true }
);
```

So as long as the value of field is kept at `0` or `1` then a bitwise "flip" will result that makes the current value the opposite of what it was at the time of the modification.

The [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) is not required, but just a way of demonstrating that the resulting value is different on every modification.

Comment: Is there any way to use this for boolean values instead of integers?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2,

#### 1) Option using [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/)

- Evaluates a boolean and returns the opposite boolean value; i.e. when passed an expression that evaluates to true, `$not` returns false; when passed an expression that evaluates to false, `$not` returns true.

```
cl.update(
  {"_id": ...}, 
  [
    { "$set": { "field": { "$not": "$field" } } }
  ]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QDUZDE6hupL)

> *Drawbacks of `$not` evaluates as false the following: null, 0, and undefined values and other values as true!*

#### 2) Option using [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)

- Will set field to true if it is false, and to false if it is any other value.

```
cl.update(
  {"_id": ...}, 
  [
    { "$set": { "field": { "$eq": [false, "$field"] } } }
  ]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LPwaF5pgZSO)

Comment: this doesnt quite work for me, its evaluating a true field to false, but when i try to run the same thing again, which is on a `false` field, it isnt doing anything, its not flipping the boolean properly, should be noted that with option 1 that you posted the inverse is true, itll flip a false boolean to true, but it wont flip a true boolean to false. got any tips for this?

Comment: for now though, ill have to do the hacky thing, and just use both.

Comment: @AustinHoward It should work, i have updated the playground link in answer.

Comment: I see it working, but its not working for me in the specific instance of my application, is it because im using mongoose's `findbyidandupdate()`? i wonder, because here you are using just `update` i wonder if thats the cause for the malfunction, though in my mind it should relatively speaking do the same thing

Comment: it should work in any update functions, probably you are missing something, for more clarification you can ask new question with your implementation and query.