# "Toggle" query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In MongoDB, How to toggle a boolean field in one document with atomic operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459789/in-mongodb-how-to-toggle-a-boolean-field-in-one-document-with-atomic-operation)

I need to update a document value, "toggling" it:

The collection is "Comment" which has boolean flag "isAdmin".

I'm going to update a given comment id, setting isAdmin false if it's true and viceversa.

However this does not work:

```
db.comments.update( { "id": "xxx" }, { $set: { isAdmin: $not isAdmin } } );
```

What's the right syntax?

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459789/in-mongodb-how-to-toggle-a-boolean-field-in-one-document-with-atomic-operation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't reference the document you find in an update like that. You'll need to do a query to find the document, and then do an update after you know what the value is. Two step process:

```
var doc = db.comments.findOne({id:"xxx"});
db.comments.update({id:"xxx"}, {$set: {isAdmin: !doc.isAdmin}});
```

Update: 
This answer has been out of date for a while (since 2.5.2):
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4362
It is now possible via the `$bit` operator `xor`, and using `findOneAndUpdate` to avoid two separate commands.

Comment: How would one do this for updating multiple documents (using multi: true)?