# Why MongoDB update field is so CPU intensive?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have social posts crawler written in C# with MongoDB WiredTiger (3.2.3) storage.

I have Post document collection with 400.000 documents in my testing server with 2-cores Xeon and 7GB memory, Windows Server 2012. Now Mongod take 2.7 Gb of memory

Document looks like:

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string SysId { get; set; }

    public Guid SiteId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

with Index

```
{
    "SiteId" : 1,
    "IsApproved" : -1,
    "Date" : -1
}
```

In my UI I have Approve toggle button with this code:

```
    ....
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Post>("Posts");

    var postStatus = await collection.AsQueryable().Select(x => new { x.Id, x.IsApproved }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == postId);

    if (postStatus == null)
          throw new EntityNotFoundException<Guid>(post.Id);

    var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(post => post.Id, postId);
    var update = Builders<Post>.Update.Set(x => x.IsApproved, !postStatus.IsApproved);

    await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

When I press Approve button multiple times I see CPU 100% utilization and after 5 seconds everything works well. Why so CPU-intensive with simplest operation ? Looks like terrible...

Comment: what storage engine is in use?

Comment: I use WiredTiger storage v3.2.3

Comment: I doubt that it is a generic MongoDB problem, but rather MongoDB waiting for IO. What I don't get is why you use async ops and then use a blocking "await". That most likely causes more overhead than it does any good. Just a wild guess, but could it be that the async stuff causes IO interrupts?

Comment: It's also probably not the wisest design choice to do a find/update separation like this. The better approach is to use what is described in [How to toggle a boolean field in one document with atomic operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36465028/2313887) using the [`$bit`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/) update operator with the [`xor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/#bitwise-xor) option to "toggle" the value per update instead. So just applying an `.updateOneAsync()` **only** here cuts a lot of IO.

Comment: Neil Lunn,thank you! But if approximate it on many other updates it looks not so good.