# How to change a boolean value without knowing what it is

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose

I am practicing Mongoose after learning SQL

Ask me a boolean value that I want to change, for example status
from false to true and vice versa.
I want the move to be dynamic

In SQL I would do this:

```
update somting set status = !status where id ....
```

How am I supposed to do this in Mongoose
In the meantime, what I tried is:

```
const task = await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
            $set: { status : !status }
        })
```

For very obvious reasons this will not work

Comment: No, I tried what's in the solution you sent, but it doesn't work, the server just crashes

Comment: It should work, because your requirement is same, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932921/8987128) in same question, there is playground also you can run and check the query.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem for me. Thank you very much, but there are many things that are not understood

Answer (score 0):

you can use $not operator to invert the boolean values.

Query to invert the boolean value is,

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id},[{$set:{bool:{$not:"$bool"}}}])`
```